# while loop not printing after passing user input

Tags: python, function, arguments

I just started out with python. I have a problem when I am calling out my function. Its not printing out when I pass in the user input. if I define a number inside of loopit() the function will print out.

Program:

```
def loopit(i): 
    numbers=[]
    while i < 6: 
        print "At the top i is %d" % i 
        numbers.append(i) 
        i= i+1 
        print "Numbers now:" , numbers 
        print "At the bottom i is %d" % i 
        print "The numbers :"
    for num in numbers: 
        print num 

print "Please input a number"
loopit(raw_input(">  "))
```

Input: 
2

Desired output :

```
At the top i is 2
Numbers now: [2]
At the bottom i is 3
The numbers :
At the top i is 3
Numbers now: [2, 3]
At the bottom i is 4
The numbers :
At the top i is 4
Numbers now: [2, 3, 4]
At the bottom i is 5
The numbers :
At the top i is 5
Numbers now: [2, 3, 4, 5]
At the bottom i is 6
The numbers :
2
3
4
5
```

Actual output:

```
####-Air:Lpthw #####$ python ex33.py
Please input a number
>  2
#####-Air:Lpthw ####$
```

So I am not getting the printed output that I was looking for after inserting the user input into the loop. However,when the loop has no arguments and a defined variable inside it, the output gets printed out correctly.

I don't know how to work around this, I am probably missing something, please help :).

Thanks a bunch !

Comment: Please just **look at your question**. Is that really the best you could do?

Comment: raw_input() returns a string, you can't increment a string, you'll have to convert the user input to an int type for the function to work.

Comment: Ohhh, thank you ! Dor-Ron and jonrsharpe.

Answer (score 1):

In your `def loopit(i):`, you are using `i` as a `int`.

But the `loopit(raw_input(">  "))` converts input to `string`. You should do the convert.

Try this

```
loopit(int(raw_input(">  ")))
```

**OR**

```
def loopit(i): 
    numbers=[]
    i = int(i)
    while i < 6: 
        print "At the top i is %d" % i 
    .....
```

Comment: Thank you! that works well. I forgot I was passing in a string with raw_input().